# Python Adding Up Values Based on User's Input in a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input, while-loop

Based on my dictionary, how can I eventually have sum of the values, based on the user's input? All the values in the dictionary start at 0 and then change based on the user's input response to the questions.
I MUST include the following codes:

```
my_dictionary = {"Dog": 0, "Cat": 0, "Brother": 0, "Sister": 0, "Daughter": 0, "Son": 0}

yes_response = ["yes", "y"]
no_response = ["no", "n"]
```

and I want the values in the dictionary to add, depending on the user's response. How do I write the code for the output to be something like below:

```
Do you have any pet(s)? Please enter Y/N: yes
You do have pet(s), that correct? Please enter Y/N: yes
How many dog(s) do you have? Please enter an integer: 2
You have 2 dog(s), is that correct? Please enter Y/N: Y
How many cat(s) do you have? Please enter an integer: 3
You have 3 cat(s), is that correct? Please enter Y/N: abcdefghhijklmnop
Sorry, your input "abcdefghhijklmnop" is invalid. Please try again.
You have 3 cat(s), is that correct. Please enter Y/N: Y

    
Do you have any siblings? Please enter Y/N: yes
You do have siblings, is that correct? Please enter Y/N: yes
How many sister(s) do you have? Please enter an integer: 1
You have 1 sister(s), is that correct? Please enter Y/N: Y
How many brother(s) do you have? Please enter an integer: None
Sorry, your input "None" is invalid. Please try again.
How many brother(s) do you have? Please enter an integer: 2
You have 2 brother(s), is that correct? Please enter Y/N: N
How many brother(s) do you have? Please enter an integer: 0
You have 0 brother(s), is that correct? Please enter Y/N: Y
    
Do you have any children? Please enter Y/N: 123456789
Sorry, incorrect response. Please try again.
Do you have any children? Please enter Y/N: no
You do not have any children, is that correct? Please enter Y/N: yes
    
Based on your valid input from the questions above, your dictionary is:  
{"Dog": 2, "Cat": 3, "Brother": 0, "Sister": 1, "Daughter": 0, "Son": 0}
```

How can I get the result like above that counts how many dogs, cats, brothers, sisters, etc, as values in a dictionary based on the user's correct answer?

Comment: You can use a defaultdict and increase value on the go

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full implementation that I show to demonstrate how this kind of thing can be "table driven". What I mean by that is that the core code is based on the lists declared at the top of the script. You can add (or take away) elements from this scripts without having to change the main code. The input prompts are rather different to yours but I'm sure you'll get the point.

```
questions = [['pets', ['Dog', 'Cat']],
             ['siblings', ['Brother', 'Sister']],
             ['children', ['Son', 'Daughter']]]
result = {x: 0 for y in questions for x in y[1]}
for q in questions:
    while True:
        a = input(f'Do you have any {q[0]}? ').lower()
        if a in ['no', 'n']:
            break
        if a not in ['yes', 'y']:
            continue
        for sq in q[1]:
            while True:
                a = input(f'How many {sq}s do you have? ')
                try:
                    n = int(a)
                    if n < 0:
                        raise ValueError
                    result[sq] += n
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please only respond with positive numbers')
        break
for k, v in result.items():
    s = '' if v == 1 else 's'
    print(f'You have {v} {k}{s}')
```